# How to set the agent of webview in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension, webview

I'm creating an extension, chrome extension, that will show my website. I want to be able to detect that the user is using my website using my *chrome extension*'s **webview**. And I want to do that only using the browser's agent. Now I've seen that page:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-setUserAgentOverride
and I've discovered that I can use `setUserAgentOverride` to change the **webview**'s agent. But the problem is that I don't know how to do it.

```
<webview id="MyView" src="https://example.com"></webview>
```

I've tried to do that, but it didn't work:

**background.js (stored within the extension):**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
  if(request.msg == "updateAgent"){
    (request.elem).setUserAgentOverride("The test's agent");
  }
});
```

**index.js (stored within the extension):**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ msg: "updateAgent", elem: ($("webview")[0]) });
```

Please help...

Comment: A `webview` in this sense is only available to Chrome Apps, a deprecated technology that shares _some_ APIs with Extensions. So it shouldn't work for you at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
Unless you're using electron:

```
<webview useragent="This is my user agent" src="https://google.com"></webview>
```